# Query to update a table with data from another table that is updated daily

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complicated query that created a table of data we needed to run some reports on. Now we'd like the query to be altered in a way that we can run it and it updates the created table with any new dates. The basic idea as I see it is I need to join the two tables, and run the update based on having records that's datetimestamp is newer than anything in table 2. For some reason it is not recognizing that table 2 has a recordcreatedate field but it does and it's labeled correctly.  I'll include the whole query, just so you can see what I'm working with.

```
Insert into table_2
select RecordCreateDate,ShipperInf_CoilId, shipperinf_Ordernumber,orderinf_ordernumber,
(select  datediff(second, min(case when PilerInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
then shipperinf_createdate else PilerInf_CreateDate end), max(case when 
ShipperInf_CreateDate= '1900-01- 01 00:00:00.000' then PilerInf_CreateDate else 
ShipperInf_CreateDate end)) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] where
ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId) as seconds, 

(select sum( case when cast([ShipperInf_Length]as float ) > 0 then cast([ShipperInf_Length] as
float) * [ShipperInf_ActualPieces] else cast(orderinf_orderedlength as float) * 
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces] end) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] 
where ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId and ShipperInf_ScreenName = 'shipping') as 
totalinch,

((select case when (select  datediff(second, min(case when PilerInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 
00:00:00.000' then shipperinf_createdate else PilerInf_CreateDate end), max(case when 
ShipperInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then PilerInf_CreateDate else 
ShipperInf_CreateDate end)) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] where 
ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId)  =0 then null else sum( case when cast
([ShipperInf_Length]as float ) > 0 then cast([ShipperInf_Length] as float) * 
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces] else cast(orderinf_orderedlength as float) * [ShipperInf_ActualPieces] 
end)end FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] where ShipperInf_CoilId = 
l2.ShipperInf_CoilId and ShipperInf_ScreenName = 'shipping')/(select  datediff(second, min(case
when PilerInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then shipperinf_createdate else 
PilerInf_CreateDate end), max(case when ShipperInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then 
PilerInf_CreateDate else ShipperInf_CreateDate end)) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].
[tblL3SendProductionData] where ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId) 
) as inchpersec,
ShipperInf_CoilIdLiftLetter, 
ActualGauge, ActualWidth, ShipperInf_Status, [ShipperInf_ActualPieces],  
[ShipperInf_LiftWeight],cast([OrderInf_MaxLiftWeight] as float) as MaxLiftWeight,  case when cast
([ShipperInf_Length]as float ) > 0 then cast([ShipperInf_Length] as float) *  
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces] else cast(orderinf_orderedlength as float) * [ShipperInf_ActualPieces]
 end as inches,

((case when cast([ShipperInf_Length]as float ) > 0 then cast([ShipperInf_Length] as float) * 
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces] else cast(orderinf_orderedlength as float) * [ShipperInf_ActualPieces]
end)/((select case when (select  datediff(second, min(case when PilerInf_CreateDate = '1900-01- 
01 00:00:00.000' then shipperinf_createdate else PilerInf_CreateDate end), max(case when 
ShipperInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then PilerInf_CreateDate else 
ShipperInf_CreateDate end)) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] where 
ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId) =0 then null else sum(case when cast
([ShipperInf_Length]as float ) > 0 then cast([ShipperInf_Length] as float) * 
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces] else cast(orderinf_orderedlength as float) * [ShipperInf_ActualPieces]
end)end 

FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] where ShipperInf_CoilId = 
l2.ShipperInf_CoilId and ShipperInf_ScreenName = 'shipping')

/(select  datediff(second, min(case
when PilerInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then shipperinf_createdate else 
PilerInf_CreateDate end), max(case when ShipperInf_CreateDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' then 
PilerInf_CreateDate else ShipperInf_CreateDate end)) FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].
[tblL3SendProductionData] where ShipperInf_CoilId = l2.ShipperInf_CoilId))) as processingseconds

FROM [nucor_historical_data].[dbo].[tblL3SendProductionData] l2 
where l2.RecordCreateDate > table_2.RecordCreateDate 
group by  RecordCreateDate,ShipperInf_CoilId, shipperinf_ordernumber, 
orderinf_ordernumber,ShipperInf_CoilIdLiftLetter,ActualGauge, ActualWidth, Shipperinf_Status,
[ShipperInf_ActualPieces],ShipperInf_LiftWeight, orderinf_MaxLiftWeight,[ShipperInf_Length],
orderinf_orderedlength
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @LastUpdateDate DATETIME
SELECT @LastUpdateDate =MAX(RecordCreateDate) FROM table_2

Insert into table_2 
....
WHERE
    l2.RecordCreateDate > @LastUpdateDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything except

```
Insert into table_2

select 
    RecordCreateDate,
    ShipperInf_CoilId, 
    shipperinf_Ordernumber,
    orderinf_ordernumber,   
    ShipperInf_CoilIdLiftLetter, 
    ActualGauge, 
    ActualWidth, 
    ShipperInf_Status, 
    ShipperInf_ActualPieces,  
    ShipperInf_LiftWeight,
    MaxLiftWeight=cast([OrderInf_MaxLiftWeight] as float),  
    --
    -- !!!! THESE VALUES ARE NOT NEEDED TO TEST WHY YOUR INSERT IS NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED.
    --
    seconds=0,
    totalinch=0,
    inchpersec=0,
    inches=0,
    processingseconds=0
FROM 
    nucor_historical_data.dbo.tblL3SendProductionData AS l2 
where 
    l2.RecordCreateDate > table_2.RecordCreateDate 
group by  
    RecordCreateDate,ShipperInf_CoilId, 
    shipperinf_ordernumber, 
    orderinf_ordernumber,
    ShipperInf_CoilIdLiftLetter,
    ActualGauge, 
    ActualWidth, 
    Shipperinf_Status,
    ShipperInf_ActualPieces,
    ShipperInf_LiftWeight, 
    orderinf_MaxLiftWeight,
    ShipperInf_Length,
    orderinf_orderedlength
```

This makes it a bit easier to determine that you probally need to get the MAX(RecordCreateDate) from table_2 to determine what is appropriate to insert.

Comment: I've done that, the error that is thrown is table_2.RecordCreateDate multipart identifier cannot be bound. But the column exists in table_2. Do I need to create an explicit join somewhere do you think?

Comment: You have no join between the two tables. There is no relationship in your query between tblL3SendProductionData AS l2 and table_2.

Comment: right, but I'm wondering if I need to add one? I've never seen the unbound error before unless it was using joins. I guess I'm just confused why it can't seem to recognize that table and column

Comment: See my other answer to this:)